# Allow HTTP OPTIONS Method in Zend 1.11.6

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, cors

I am trying to enable Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) on an old project done in Zend 1.11.6 and the issue appears to be an exception thrown on the initial flight test `OPTIONS` request. Here is the full respone to an HTTP OPTIONS request:

**Headers:**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, x-requested-with, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 26 Nov 2014 00:38:47 GMT
Server: Apache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Cnection: close
```

**BODY**:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "data": "Exception",
    "message": "Method \"optionsaction\" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()",
    "request": "/authenticate",
    "version": "v1",
    "parameters": {
    "controller": "authenticate",
    "action": "options",
    "module": "default"
    }
}
```

I tracked down the error message to `Zend_Controller_Action.__call()` in `library/Zend/Controller/Action.php.` My question is: where is the appropriate place to modify the framework to allow this request? I'm ok with doing this on a controller by controller basis or project wide.

Also, I enabled CORS via `.htaccess` which I have pasted below:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "DELETE"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "OPTIONS"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Here is my Authenticate Controller Options Action:

```
public function optionsAction()
{
    $this->view->data = Array();
    $this->view->success = true;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of your authenticate controller ? (especially around the options action, this method seems to be missing)

Comment: I don't have an options action. I just added one, I'll update the post. It hasn't changed the response.

Answer (score 0):

Have look at Zend_Rest_Route::match(), you need to teach/extend it to map OPTIONS method to optionsAction() in your controller.